# MySQL w/ MAMP - Symbolic link disappears after I quit MAMP

Tags: mysql, macos, mamp

How can I change my MAMP mysql.sock file path from

**/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock**

to something else that doesn't get deleted whenever I quit MAMP or restart the computer? I'm running Mac OS X Yosemite.

Details: MAMP / MySQL socket file gets erased every time I quit MAMP.

This is understandable, given that the mysql.sock file is stored in a tmp folder.

Current path is /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock

Every time I run MAMP I have to recreate a symlink using the following command:

sudo ln -s [source] [target]

Source = **/var/mysql/mysql.sock** OR **/tmp/mysql.sock**

Target = /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock

This is a known problem and a few answers have been given to other questions like this, but none provide a way to change where the MAMP mysql.sock file is stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this has nothing to do with MAMP.

This file -> mysql.sock is not a definitive file, so to speak.
It's created every time you start mysqld, and it's deleted when you stop mysqld or restart/shutdown your computer.

So, to solve this you have to start mysqld every time you're going to do some database operation.

Or you can configure it as a startup program/script. Once you do this, your problems will be solved.